# What is the difference between this: and :this?

Tags: ruby

What does the colon denote when used at the beginning and at the end of something? I think that a colon at the begging of something (e.g. `:set_cart`) denotes a method. Is this correct? Here are a few examples:

```
<%= button_to "Checkout", new_order_path, method: :get %>
<%= button_to "Empty Cart", @cart, method: :delete,
    data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

**Edit: Another Example**

```
before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: This is a symbol, if you want to know more there are plenty of resources about this on the internet but you can check that post for instance: http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/ : )

Comment: @Sparda "This is a symbol" is not very helpful if you don't specify you're referring to `:this` rather than `this:`.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm well as far as I know, without the subtleties of Hashes and stuff, they are both symbols...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colon at the **beginning** of something denotes a Ruby [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html) object.

```
> :name.class
=> Symbol
```

A colon at the **end** of something denotes a Symbol key in a Ruby [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html) object. This new Hash syntax was introduced in Ruby 1.9.

```
> hash = { key: 'val' }
=> {:key=>"val"}
```

When they are used together, as expected, it creates a hash pair with a key and value that are symbols.

```
> { key: :val }
=> {:key => :val}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the new syntax for [symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html)-indexed hashes, introduced (I believe) in Ruby 1.9.

Instead of the old `{ :key => 'value' }` you can now write `{ key: 'value' }`. Under the hood the hash is exactly the same, so it's only really a notation change.

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > { key: 'value' }
 => {:key=>"value"}
```

In your example, method: :delete is just a different way of writing :method => :delete.

Comment: In addition, the OP's example code makes use of method-calling convention whereby hash key/value syntax found at the end of a method call is rolled up into a single `Hash` param.